# How can I make a glossy BDSF shader reflect the true color of an emission?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, reflection

I have a red glossy shader on a car and a different object with a blue emission shader, the blue emission is reflecting off the glossy shader as yellow. How can I make the reflection the true color of the emission instead of yellow? An image of the problem is below, thanks for any help I appreciate it.

[image]